# Can not share image in Gmail and Instagram

Tags: android, share-intent

I want to share Image via `shareIntent`. My code is given below :

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(list.get(position).getFilePath()));
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,  "Sending from myApp");//gmail-subject
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  "Image 1234");//gmail-body
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image 1234");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));
```

I am able to send image in **WhatsApp** and **Facebook** but not in **Gmail** or **Instagram**.

When trying to share via **Gmail** it shows me

> `Can't attach file`

and for **Instagram** it shows me

> Unable to load image

.

Is anything else required to add in `shareIntent` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + yourFile.getRouteFile());
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            String fileExtension = FileExtension.getFileExtension(file);
                            Log.d(TAG, "fileExtension: " + fileExtension);
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath());
                            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                            share.setType(fileExtension + "/*");
                            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share file"));
                        }
```

get file extension

```
public static String getFileExtension(File file) {
        String name = file.getName();
        try {
            return name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works fine. But there is 1 problem : share.setType(fileExtension + "/*"); due to this line it shows me small list of sharable apps compared to share.setType("image/*");

Comment: can use only image

Comment: But I can also share documents using share.setType("image/*");